# Show hide related li when alphabetic name is clicked

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have below code,

```
    <ul class="topindex">
    <li><h4><a title="A folder" href="#A-folder" rel="nofollow" class="index-letters">A</a></h4></li>
    <li><h4><a title="B folder" href="#B-folder" rel="nofollow" class="index-letters">B</a></h4></li>
    <li><h4><a title="C folder" href="#C-folder" rel="nofollow" class="index-letters">C</a></h4></li>
    <li><h4><a title="D folder" href="#D-folder" rel="nofollow" class="index-letters">D</a></h4></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="index-list">
    <li><a name="A-folder" id="A-folder"></a>
    <h5><a title="Back to index" href="#tags_top" rel="nofollow">A</a></h5>

    <ul class="links">
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="http://www.related.link" title="A" rel="nofollow">A text</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a name="B-folder" id="B-folder"></a>
    <h5><a title="Back to index" href="#tags_top" rel="nofollow">B</a></h5>

    <ul class="links">
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="http://www.related.link" title="B" rel="nofollow">B text</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a name="C-folder" id="C-folder"></a>
    <h5><a title="Back to index" href="#tags_top" rel="nofollow">C</a></h5>
    <ul class="links">
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="http://www.related.link" title="C" rel="nofollow">C text</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

My object is to show only related text and an alphabetic letter is clicked, for example, if "A" is clicked, show "A Text".

I have tried below text, but doesnt seem to fully work, it only shows the letter heading but not the text.

```
    <script>
    $('.index-list li').hide();
    $("a.index-letters").click(function() {
    $('.index-list li').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).attr('name')).show();   
    });

    </script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links you click on have no name attribute, so this `$('#'+$(this).attr('name'))` will fail. Also, `$('.index-list li').hide();` is hiding all your list items when you just need to hide the parents, so use `$('.index-list > li')` instead.

Try:

```
$('.index-list > li').hide();
$("a.index-letters").click(function () {
    $('.index-list > li').hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).parent().show();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ARtU2/)**